# Webpack dev-server Unexpected identifier error

Tags: reactjs, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I am new to React+Webpack. As a part of the tutorial, I have written a `webpack.config.js` file. This is the file content:

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    devtool: 'inline-source-map',
    entry: [
        'webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080/',
        'webpack/hot/only-dev-server',
        './src'
    ],
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, 'public'),
        filename: 'bundle.js'
    },
    resolve:{
        moduleDirectories: ['node_modules', 'src'],
        extensions: ['', '.js']
    }
    module:{
        loaders:[
            {
                test: /\.jsx?$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loaders: ['react-hot','babel?presets[]=react,presets[]=es2015']
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins:[
        new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
        new webpack.NoErrorsPlugin()
    ]
};
```

I am getting Unexpected Identifier error at line number 19-> `module:{...},`

Error details:

```
/home/adi/testcode/webpack.config.js:19
    module:{
    ^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
    at Object.exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:78:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:543:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:488:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:447:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:439:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:498:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at module.exports (/usr/lib/node_modules/webpack/bin/convert-argv.js:80:13)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js:39:40)
```

I have checked `webpack.config.js` examples, and found what I wrote is correct. Yet it is not working as expected.  Unfortunately, I couldn't find solution in GitHub issues, StackOverflow, and Quora.

Where am I making a mistake?

Answer (score 21):

You forgot a comma before the module property

Comment: that's embarrassing :/ . Thank you for the help :)